# Make TDES working with 16-byte input from existing function worked with 8-byte input

Tags: c++, c, arduino, 3des

currently I use the DES from this library for Arduino (https://github.com/Octoate/ArduinoDES). 
But this library is only working with 8-byte of input. 
So the question is how can I make this library working with my input of 16 bytes? Is there any ways?

Comment: Call it twice? DES inherently works on one 8 byte block at a time.

Comment: You might want to look up the different ways (modes) of using block ciphers - ECB, CBC, etc.

Comment: can ECB work with 16-byte input?